# i18n in datePipe Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have an application that it's running in two language ( i can change an choose the language i want bu using i18n) English / French.

At the moment i can get the date only in english even if i select the French Language.

```
   <div class="information">
              {{ information.date | information:'EEEE'}} {{information.date | date:'d'}} {{ information.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ information.date |
              date:'yyyy'}}
        </div>
```

At the moment i get it like this Monday 17 August 2018, i want to get the french one too Lundi 17 Aout 2018

Is there a way to change the date depending on what language is selected ?

Comment: It usually depends on your browser settings. If the browser runs in French your output will accord to french rules. Read this tutorial, which maybe helps: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app

Comment: @DiabolicWords At the moment in my application, i can change the language by my own. my problem is with the PipeDate, i think there's a trick because by default it will stay in ENGLISH, i need to figure out how to change it in French when i change the language in my application.

Comment: I see. That‘s why I added the link to my post above. This article covers exactly this issue.

Comment: Okay, I read the tutorial on my own. The most important message is this: **You need to build and deploy a separate version of the app for each supported language.** So there won‘t be a glimpse of a chance to switch the entire language pack at runtime. I18N at runtime only helps you with substitution of translations by key.

Comment: @DiabolicWords Ouuuuuch i need to find a solution

Comment: Maybe by using a pipe so i can translate the day/month in french

Comment: Of course, this is possible. But it gets tricky. You have to manipulate the entire date string, though. parsing the date string and replacing days and month; rearranging the order of the date components. But I was a suitable way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @DiabolicWords Could you advise me how to do it please ?

Comment: Will do, but am currently on the way. I'll get back to you a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create and use a custom pipe as described here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

enum Days {
    Dimanche,
    Lundi,
    Mardi,
    Mercredi,
    Jeudi,
    Vendredi,
    Samedi
}

enum Months {
    Janvier,
    Février,
    Mars,
    Avril,
    Mai,
    Juin,
    Juillet,
    Août,
    Septembre,
    Octobre,
    Novembre,
    Décembre
}

@Pipe({ name: 'frenchDate' })
export class FrenchDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(date: Date) {

        const dayOfMonth = date.getDate();
        const nameOfDay = Days[date.getDay()];
        const nameOfMonth = Months[date.getMonth()];
        const year = date.getYear();

        const result = nameOfDay + ' ' + dayOfMonth + ' ' + nameOfMonth + ' ' + year;

       return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, here you go. this Pipe should do what you want. You only have to put an if-clause around it that checks whether the french date is currently wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have no more knowledge about i18n but after study docs i ensure that this code will work well for you .

**ng serve --configuration=fr**

use this command for run your program .here ***fr*** refers to the French language identifier.

If you want to import locale data for other languages, you can do it manually in **app.module.ts** file.

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr');

Comment: Sir i think there's a trick to do with https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes, i can get the language in my localstorage i want to affect the date by it, but didn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Only the en-US locale data comes with Angular. To localize dates in another language, you must import the corresponding locale data

Comment: The main issue is that she wants to switch between these languages at runtime which is not entirely possible. You can tell Angular to use the other set of translation files, but the static surroundings of the currently running language pack will stay untouched.